# What's the reason that xlwings does not support referencing Range with a sheet reference?

Tags: xlwings

I appreciate the fact that xlwings makes it easier to reference Ranges by allowing putting in the Sheet name and sheet index in the Range constructor, but it seems weird to me that it doesn't support providing a sheet object/reference for the same purpose, which would seem a lot more "object-oriented" and would map to the VBA ''' sht.Range("A1")''' construct a lot better. Is there a reason why this is not supported in addition to using sheet name and sheet index? Of course you can do Range(sheet.name, "A1"), but that seems like an unnecessary extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open issue for that, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/92). The reason why it's not there yet is that originally the API was heavily influenced by [DataNitro](https://datanitro.com/) and they're missing the Sheet object altogether. But it's a small change so it should make it in soon.

Comment: upvoted and accepted. wonder when this will be available. 0.3.6 to be released soon?

Comment: hopefully within the next few weeks, yes... pull requests are also always welcome ;-)

Comment: Actually, do you know of a good comparison of DataNitro and xlwings? What does xlwings aim to address that DataNitro doesnt?

Comment: Well, the main purpose was to produce something free and open-source. In the meantime, there's a lot more than just that: Mac compatibility, pip installable, no special method needed to handle DataFrames etc etc.

Comment: And I bet they don't have as dedicated a supporter and maintainer like yourself!